# Capturing stdout in C# from a dll

Tags: c#, .net, threadpool, named-pipes

I am trying to use the following code to capture/redirect blind printf from a dll to a WPF text box.

dll:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "stdafx.h"
#define EXTERN_DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)


extern "C" EXTERN_DLL_EXPORT int startPipe()
{
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    printf("hey");
    return 20;
}

//Morepipe2, etc just return different test words.
```

C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Pipes;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;

namespace PipeTest {


public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    private NamedPipeServerStream serverPipe;
    private NamedPipeClientStream clientPipe;
    private int id;
    private StreamReader stm;
    private HandleRef hr11;
    private String txt;

    private delegate void updateCallback(string pipetext);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    protected static extern bool SetStdHandle(int nStdHandle, IntPtr hConsoleOutput);

    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();

        id = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id; // make this instance unique
        serverPipe = new NamedPipeServerStream("consoleRedirect" + id, PipeDirection.In, 1);
        clientPipe = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "consoleRedirect" + id, PipeDirection.Out, PipeOptions.WriteThrough);
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => {
            serverPipe.WaitForConnection();
            using (stm = new StreamReader(serverPipe)) {
                while (serverPipe.IsConnected) {
                    try {
                        txt = stm.ReadLine();
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt))

                            UpdateElement(txt + "\n");
                    } catch (IOException) {
                        break; // normal disconnect
                    }
                }
            }
        }, null);
        clientPipe.Connect();
        hr11 = new HandleRef(clientPipe,
         clientPipe.SafePipeHandle.DangerousGetHandle());
        SetStdHandle(-11, hr11.Handle); // redirect stdout to my pipe

        PipeServer.morePipe1();
        PipeServer.morePipe2();

        PipeServer.startPipe();
        PipeServer.morePipe1();
        PipeServer.morePipe2();
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        PipeServer.startPipe();
        PipeServer.startPipe();
    }

    private void ender() {
        //clientPipe.Dispose();
        //serverPipe.Dispose();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        PipeServer.startPipe();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        PipeServer.morePipe1();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        PipeServer.morePipe2();
    }

    private void UpdateElement(string pipetext) {
        if (textBox1.Dispatcher.CheckAccess() == false) {
            updateCallback uCallBack = new updateCallback(UpdateElement);
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(uCallBack, pipetext);
        } else {
            textBox1.Text += pipetext;
        }
    }
}

public static class PipeServer {

     private const CallingConvention conv = CallingConvention.StdCall;

    [DllImport(@"PipeServer2.dll", CallingConvention = conv)]
    public static extern int startPipe();

    [DllImport(@"PipeServer2.dll", CallingConvention = conv)]
    public static extern int morePipe1();


}
}
```

This code does not work the way it is now. However these are my issues:

1. If the module level private variables are moved to mainwindow(), it will work and show everything the textbox.  I can call multiple methods in the dll and show output as long as they are in mainwindow().
2. Even if it does work, once mainwindow() completes it no longer logs any output when I click on the buttons that call the dll. My expectation is the buttons should call the dll, and there should be data written to stdout/pipe, and the thread should still pick it up (am I wrong here?). I thought making the the variables module level would help, but I am getting no result if I do that.